# Unable to install MongoDB in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: mongodb

When will MongoDB be available for Ubuntu 22.04 LTS ? I require MongoDB for my work purposes.

Comment: Welcome to Askubuntu. Have you tried installing? If so, did you have problems? If you did have problems like error messages, please edit your question and copy and paste the terminal output into your question. Make sure to include the errors. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

MongoDB can be installed on Ubuntu with the use of the following commands.

Open a Terminal window(Ctrl+Alt+T).

Paste the following commands into the terminal to install MongoDB;

```
sudo apt update
```

To install dependencies:

```
sudo apt install dirmngr gnupg apt-transport-https ca-certificates software-properties-common
```

Download and add the MongoDB GPG key with the following command

```
wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-5.0.asc | sudo apt-key add -
```

Then create a list for MongoDB using;

```
echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/5.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-5.0.list
```

Update the local package database using

```
sudo apt update
```

Now install MongoDB with the following command;

```
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

Start the MongoDB service and enable it to start automatically after rebooting the system using;

```
systemctl start mongod
systemctl enable mongod
```

The status of MongoDB service can be checked using `systemctl status mongod`

It should return an output similar to the one below;

```
mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset>
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2022-08-19 14:56:46 UTC; 4min ago
       Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
   Main PID: 3278 (mongod)
     Memory: 193.7M
        CPU: 14.206s
     CGroup: /system.slice/mongod.service
             └─3278 /usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf
```

To verify whether the installation has completed successfully by running the following command.

```
mongo --eval 'db.runCommand({ connectionStatus: 1 })'
```

output should be like;

```
MongoDB shell version v5.0.6
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("9722b711-f1f0-43f2-aec6-f6172da9d237") }
MongoDB server version: 5.0.6
{
        "authInfo" : {
                "authenticatedUsers" : [ ],
                "authenticatedUserRoles" : [ ]
        },
        "ok" : 1
}
```

That is all about installation.    [SOURCE](https://wiki.crowncloud.net/?How_to_Install_Latest_MongoDB_on_Ubuntu_22_04#Add%20MongoDB%20GPG%20Key)

For more information regarding user creation and other topic kindly visit this [website](https://wiki.crowncloud.net/?How_to_Install_Latest_MongoDB_on_Ubuntu_22_04#Add%20MongoDB%20GPG%20Key).

Comment: Didn't work for me. These are the responses I get, while installing on Ubuntu 22.04 The following packages have unmet dependencies: mongodb-org-mongos : Depends: libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.1) but it is not installable mongodb-org-server : Depends: libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.1) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of looking for a solution I was satisfied with, I finally stumbled across one! Hope this helps anyone else looking to install MongoDB community edition without sacrificing security by using libssl1.1 (the solution here uses >3.0.

MongoDB has the repository for Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish) hidden away. It definitely still isn't on the documentation installation pages as of the time I am posting this. Check it out yourself: https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/jammy/mongodb-org/

The following code will add the repository and install the latest mongodb-org on your system:

```
sudo apt-get install wget gpg
wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-6.0.asc | gpg --dearmor > packages.mongodb.gpg
sudo install -D -o root -g root -m 644 packages.mongodb.gpg /etc/apt/keyrings/packages.mongodb.gpg
echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/packages.mongodb.gpg] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu jammy/mongodb-org/6.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-6.0.list
rm -f packages.mongodb.gpg
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

From: https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/installing-mongodb-over-ubuntu-22-04/159931/90

1. `wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-6.0.asc |  gpg --dearmor | sudo tee /usr/share/keyrings/mongodb.gpg > /dev/null`
2. `echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/mongodb.gpg ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu jammy/mongodb-org/6.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-6.0.list`
3. `sudo apt update`
4. `sudo apt install mongodb-org`

Start the service with `sudo systemctl start mongod`.